# Is it possible to create a bubble chart with dc.js with the x and y axis as forces?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I want to create a bubble chart, but instead of having values for x and y, I want them to be forces, just like [Mikes Bostock's example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/bubble-chart) of bubble chart (similar to a force directed graph). I found there was a [dc add-on for previous versions](https://github.com/Intellipharm/dc-addons#bubble-cloud) but there is nothing that works with the latest versions of dc and d3.

Comment: I think your best bet is to port the existing dc-addons chart from D3v3 to D3v5. It [shouldn’t be hard](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md). If you do, please consider open sourcing it!